# Would you use Amazon CloufFront as a Cache for a website?

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have been using Amazon CloudFront for a while now as a cache and edge location for my css, js, image files. I am now thinking about using it for hosting all of my static html files as well. In essence my www.example.com and example.com will be hosted via CloudFront and I will use a separate tomcat server at my.example.com for all the dynamic stuff.

Any feedback about this? Suggestions?

Thanks,

Assaf

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what CloudFront is designed for. I think you will find this approach is typical of many high traffic web sites.

The only downside is added cost...

Answer (score 0):

I used cloudfront for some time, but recently switched to [Google Page Speed Service](http://code.google.com/speed/pss/). It is a little light on features currently, but it deals with edge locations and all the tricks required to speed up you page.

It is currently in beta, but I've had no problems over the 2 months I've been using it. The only question is how much it'll cost when it leaves beta.